# How to delete database content in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller, codeigniter-4

I want to delete content from my database, How do I pass the ID in URL to execute this?

```
public function delete($id = null)
    {

     $model = new PostModel();

     $data['post'] = $model->where('id', $id)->delete();

     return redirect()->to( base_url('admin/posts') );
    }
}
```

I had

```
example.com/post/delete/id
```

but didn't work.

Comment: You need to m$ake a `controller` named post and create a `function delete($id = false)` and call `model` function `delete()` from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1: create route

```
$routes->get('posts/delete/(:num)', 'PostsController::delete/$1');
```

step 2: Use PostModel as (use App\Models\PostModel;) at the top. Now create a method in PostsController class.

```
public function delete($id = null)
{

 $model = new PostModel();

 $data['post'] = $model->where('id', $id)->delete();

 return redirect()->to( base_url('admin/posts') );
}
```

step 3: create a link as

```
<a href=" <?php  echo base_url("posts/delete/". $post['id']); ?>">Remove</a>
```

it should work

Comment: @jan

This solution is working correctly .... but when I use 'post_id' field instead of 'id' it doesn't work.

Comment: Let's address the question to @kuldeep-singh. I only added some formatting for clarity. Kuldeep is the smart one.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL look okay, you might have problem with your Model or view. The controller code is fine. Post the model or view code also.
You can get help from the following [this example](https://www.tutsmake.com/codeigniter-4-first-crud-example-tutorial/).